# Run delegate method with BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, delegates

In my class I have a static method

```
public static void DoWork(int param) ...
```

I want to run that method like:

```
Form.BeginInvoke(DoWork, param);
```

Is this operation possible?

I tried with the MethodInvoker class ... but I don't want to define the method body inline.
Is there any generic delegate? Or do you know any other way of calling this without defining a delegate object (`private delegate void DoWorkDelegate(int param)`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
form.BeginInvoke((Action<int>)DoWork, param);
```

As a side note, `MethodInvoker` has the advantage of special handling - it can invoke that one with typed-invoke, rather than reflection-invoke - and perhaps more importantly offers checking of the args ahead of time; *personally* I would just use:

```
form.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {DoWork(param);});
```

Comment: @Onkelborg - no; actually this *particular* one is 2.0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: You might want to mention that BeginInvoke is an instance method.